# Should I include large files in PWA build for offline capability?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I am developing a PWA with Vue 3 CLI that grabs *some* of it's content from a seperate CMS/API. The application is a touchscreen game and a primary use case is running without an internet connection, although the user environment is controlled and the game can be updated with latest updates sync'd and cached via ServiceWorkers when required.

When I build my app, Webpack performance recommendations warn of assets larger than the recommended size limit; in this case an intro video (25MB) and some font files (300kB each).

Should I be serving the video and fonts (and other large files) from the CMS/API and keeping my Vue app build as small as possible, bearing in mind the offline functionality being important? Or is there a good reason to package the fonts and video in the Vue JS build output?

This is my first PWA, so am just looking for confirmation whether to follow the Webpack guidelines in this case, given the app functioning properly offline is a priority?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit you can store depending on your browser [How Much Can You Store](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker#how_much_can_you_store)

Me personally i would not recommend to store such large video files. If it is not absolute needed for your users offline experience.

Answer (score 1):

If the video is not mandatory to play the game, I would not cache it by default, but give the user the opportunity to do it if she wants.

Some players might have low quota data plans and want to not show the video.

The fonts look like a good asset to put in cache.